# SQL query update in C#

Tags: c#, sql-update

My table `Student` has 4 columns `ID`, `Name`, `FamilyName` and `Age`.

I ask user to give specific ID and then one of the columns to update with query. 
My update query `CommandText` is as follows:

```
public void Update (OleDbConnection connection, string Name, int ID)
{
    _command.Connection = connection;
    _command.CommandText = String.Format("UPDATE Student SET Name = Name WHERE ID = ID");
    _command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

In `main()` by the use of a switch I am trying to manage which column the user wants to update. like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("which do you want to edit, name, family name or age?");

var answer2 = Console.ReadLine().Trim().ToLower();

switch(answer2)
{
    case "name":
```

My question is: in my query in `CommandText`, is it possible to write

```
UPDATE Student 
SET Name = Name || FamilyName = Name || Age = Name 
WHERE ID = ID
```

Comment: No, that's not valid SQL. I'm not even sure of your intent with that query. It looks like you're trying to match `Name` to any of those columns (which is still incorrect syntax), but you don't have it as part of the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: What is `...SET Name = Name` supposed to do?

Comment: Also, as you have written the current query command, you are not passing the values for ID and Name. You need to use a parameterized query

Comment: maybe consider using Entity Framework where the property changes are handled automagically ?

Comment: in ...SET Name = Name , the first Name is the name of a column in my database and the second Name is what user is giving as an input to update.

Comment: sorry:( I am not familiar with parameterized query and Entity framework. What comes to my mind is, writing 3 queries and call them by the 3 cases I am writing in the switch.

Comment: You should look into Expression Tree's, but a primitive solution would be to use reflection.  But I would implore you to leverage one of the many tools rather than roll your own.  Object Relational Mappers are a common tool and have a significant amount of domain logic behind them.

Comment: `SET Name = Name` does not update the `Name` column with the user's value.  You'd need a parameter to do that.

Comment: [Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/)?

Comment: I still don't understand why you're trying to set all 3 of those values to `Name`. Setting `Age` to `Name` doesn't seem to make any sense. Are you saying `Name` is just a variable? If so, it would be much clearer if you used something like `Value`.

Answer (score -1):

No, that's not a correct SQL query. SET Name = Name will not update Name column like this. You need to pass the parameter value to your query.

Comment: This is just a rewrite of the comments above as an "answer". A very low quality answer. At least try to explain why "Name = Name" doesn't work and try to add an example of a parameterized query before writing an "answer"